# Can I limit the CPU usage of a website for testing?

Tags: web, flash, cpu-usage

We have developed a website that has quite a lot of flash in it and it seems to be hanging on some machines using firefox, these machines are a lower spec than our development machines and we cannot recreate the problem locally.

Ideally we want to somehow limit the CPU usage to maybe just a single core when browsing the website in the office so we can try and replicate the situation of our users.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the CPU affinity of the Browser and the flash plugin process. There are also some slowdown utilities that can emulate a slower CPU

http://www.classicdosgames.com/utilities.html

Comment: ah this seems like what I need. I remember now using something similar a few yrs ago when trying to play an old win 3.11 game that was going at the speed of light on my win 98 PC!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

VMware will let you choose to run your machine in a configurable amount of cores and processors.  As far as I can tell, it won't let you downclock.  But going down to one core might do the trick for you.

Comment: I had thought of this, but currently not running vmware or virtual pc, s would take lots of time to sort out